# Object Required Run-Time Error VBA when searching different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to VBA so a lot of my code is what I have researched on the internet and put together.  A bit background to what I am trying to achieve: -

I have two works books which have an identical layout.  One work book is my original where the VBA code is held and the other is a type of overlay document.  I have a column with a codes in the Overlay and need to search the original work book same column for this code if its found then copy entire row from overlay into the original and deleting the row found in the original, if its not found in the original just to copy row across.

The line of code I am getting the run-time error on is: -

```
Set rngFound = Workbooks("OverLay").Worksheets("Overlay").Range("G:G").Find(What:=r.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
```

Below is an extract of the code I am using.

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet   'Current active worksheet (original version)
Dim sht2 As Worksheet   'Worksheet in OverLay
Dim rngFound As Range

Set sht2 = Workbooks("Overlay").Worksheets("Overlay")

With Workbooks("Original").Worksheets("Formatted")
    lastRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With sht2
    For Each Row In .Range("G:G")
        Set rngFound = Workbooks("OverLay").Worksheets("Overlay").Range("G:G").Find(What:=r.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            rngFound.Copy
            Workbooks("Original").Worksheets("Formatted").Range(rngFound).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Use the extension when referring to a workbook. e.g. `Set rngFound = Workbooks("OverLay.xlsx")....`. You can get the correct name by activating the workbook and using `?activeworkbook.name` in the Immediate window.

Comment: @Jeeped I have made the amendment as you suggested but I am still getting that error

Comment: what's that `r` whose "value" you're trying to find? Looks like you'd type `Row`

Comment: It's expecting `r` to be a range object, if `r` hasn't been set then you have a missing object - hence the "Object required" error.

Comment: @MacroMan thanks  for pointing that out, it is not set.  I am not sure what I should set this as. should it be a range as I and want to search a range of cells i.e. a column

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by showing you what's wrong:

```
Dim sht1 As Worksheet '// <~~ This never gets used?
Dim sht2 As Worksheet   'Worksheet in OverLay
Dim rngFound As Range

Set sht2 = Workbooks("Overlay").Worksheets("Overlay")

With Workbooks("Original").Worksheets("Formatted")
    lastRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With sht2
    For Each Row In .Range("G:G")
'// 'Row' in the above line will be treated as a variant as it hasn't been declared.
'// As such, it will most likely default to a Range object, which means you are
'// actually looping through each cell in that column. The lesson here is "be explicit"
'// and make sure the code is looking at exactly what you want it to look at.
        Set rngFound = Workbooks("OverLay").Worksheets("Overlay").Range("G:G").Find(What:=r.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
'// You've already set this sheet to 'sht2' so just use that instead. Also, as
'// we know - 'r' has not been set and so causes an error.
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            rngFound.Copy
            Workbooks("Original").Worksheets("Formatted").Range(rngFound).PasteSpecial
'// 'rngFound' is already a range object, no need to wrap it in a Range() method.
        End If
    Next
End With
```

This can be re-written as such:

```
Dim originalWS     As Worksheet '// give your variables meaningful names!
Dim overlayWS      As Worksheet
Dim rngSearchParam As Range
Dim rngFound       As Range

Set originalWS = Workbooks("Original").Sheets("Formatted")
Set overlayWS = Workbooks("Overlay").Sheets("Overlay")

With overlayWS
    For Each rngSearchParam In Intersect(.Range("G:G"), .UsedRange)

        Set rngFound = .Range("G:G").Find(rngSearchParam.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            originalWS.Range(rngFound.Address).Value = rngFound.Value
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Although it seems like your searching a column, for a value defined by a cell in the same column - so not sure what the "end goal" is here. Hopefully it clarifies the issues you've been having though

Comment: Can I ask what does this section of the code do: - If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            originalWS.Range(rngFound.Address).Value = rngFound.Value   I am not sure I understand that the line originalWS.Range(rngFound).... is doing

Comment: What I want to do it if the line is found then delete it from the original and then copy the row from the overlay into to the original and if it is not found then just copy the row straight over.